# ¿cómo modificar la propiedad de un elemento usando el useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, usestate, props, useeffect

Tengo el siguiente useState que trae el estado inicial de los elementos de un form:

```
const [book, setBook] = useState({
    name:'',
    author:'',
    edition: ''
  })


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div>
     <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} type="text" id="name" className="form-control" value={name}/>
     <input name="author" onChange={handleChange} type="text" id="author" className="form-control" value={author}/>
     <input name="edition" onChange={handleChange} type="number" id="edition" className="form-control" value={edition}/>
  </div>
     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Cuando actualizo mi objeto, el siguiente Handle se ejecuta:

```
const handleChange = e => { 
        setBook({
        ...Book, 

        [e.target.name]:e.target.value 
    })
}
```

Requiero que si el campo 'Edition' no es actualizado, se guarde el valor NULL.
He intentado modificar directamente el estado inicial para volverlo NULL de la siguiente forma `id_usuario: NULL` y de cierta manera funciona, pero también genera una alerta: *Warning: value prop on input should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or undefined for uncontrolled components.*

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de cambiar este state a Null cuando el campo no fue modificado?

Comment: React nos dice que no se puede hacer eso, el input ya tiene un `type=number`, si lo que necesitas es guardar `type null` en la base de datos para ese campo, debes hacerlo desde el backend al recibir una cadena vacía desde el frontend react.